# How to enable Self-service Configuration Management on a Cloud VM through HTTP interface?

Tags: configuration, ansible

I am planning to build a SaaS where users will be able to create a new server instance on cloud themselves which would host a certain software. You can call it a single-tenancy SaaS, which suits the line of software which I am planning to offer.

The part which deals with creating a server instance on cloud is fairly straight forward: using DigitalOcean or AWS API. Once the cloud server has been created, SaaS app would need to run some configurations on the newly created server to setup the software and dependencies. I prefer an agent-less configuration tool like Ansible as it reduces the complexity of the process.

I have gone through Ansible's documentation but I am not able to figure out how I would be able to programmatically trigger a certain playbook and pass it some variables using an HTTP interface which I can integrate in my SaaS.

I was thinking on the following lines:

1. Using another agent-less configuration management tool with a powerful HTTP API interface.
2. Using a generic HTTP API of some kind which lets me run ansible command line.

Any ideas of what would be the best method to proceed in my current constraints (which are (i) single tenancy SaaS, (ii) agent-less configuration, (iii) self-service configuration through HTTP)

Thanks

Comment: This question is waaaay too broad for SO.

Comment: Well, the question is related to architecture of a SaaS. It is bound to be broad. Isn't StackOverflow the right place to ask questions about software architecture?

Comment: No, SO it not the right place for that. But you can check the on-topic help page of programmers.se to see if it might fit there. When in doubt search their meta site an/or ask a question on the meta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are describing something close to Ansible existing http://www.ansible.com/tower which has an http API. Since that probably doesn't exactly fit your use-case wrapping ansible with a thin api wrapper sounds like your best option. You could trigger ansible jobs with Jenkins or use a more flexible framework for running tasks like http://www.celeryproject.org.

For the initial configuration of your server you may want to consider running ansible-pull (or just ansible locally) on bring-up.  If you have a handful of configurations that will be starting points for your users. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Celery looks like an overkill for my needs. Jenkins definitely looks like it can provide the thin wrapper functionality which would work for me.
I have looked at Tower API closely and it seems that the callback functionality can be used to achieve what I need. Obviously I will have to try it to be sure.